# checking for typeof error in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

In JS it doesn't seem possible to check if an argument passed to a function is actually of the type 'error' or an instance of Error.

For example, this is not valid:

`typeof err === 'error'`

since there are only 6 possible types (in the form of strings):

The typeof operator returns type information as a string. There are six possible values that `typeof` returns:

> "number", "string", "boolean", "object", "function" and "undefined".

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/259s7zc1%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

But what if I have a simple use case like this:

```
function errorHandler(err) {

    if (typeof err === 'error') {
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        console.error('Unexpectedly, no error was passed to error handler. But here is the message:',err);
    }
}
```

so what is the best way to determine if an argument is an instance of Error?

is the `instanceof` operator of any help?

Comment: Yes, use `err instanceof Error`

Comment: @colecmc won't that be problematic if the error might have come from code in a frame or another window?  In that case there will be different prototype Error objects, and instanceof won't work as expected. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: @Doin, I don't think so. It will just validate the actual error object.

Comment: @colecmc, I think you'll find that if you've thrown `err` in (say) an iframe, but then pass it to the parent window for handing, you'll get `(err instanceof Error) === false`.  That's because the iframe and its parent window have distinct, different `Error` object prototypes.  Similarly an object like `obj = {};` will, when passed to a function running in a different window, yeild `(obj instanceof Object)===false`.  (Even worst, in IE, if you keep a reference to obj after its window is destroyed or navigated, trying to call object prototype fns like `obj.hasOwnProperty()` will throw errors!)

Comment: how do you check for the type of error tho? i.e. `catch((err)=>{if (err === ENOENT)` returns `ENOENT is not defined` error?

Answer (score 451, accepted):

You can use the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator (but see caveat below!).

```
var myError = new Error('foo');
myError instanceof Error // true
var myString = "Whatever";
myString instanceof Error // false
```

The above won't work if the error was thrown in a different window/frame/iframe than where the check is happening. In that case, the `instanceof Error` check will return false, even for an `Error` object. In that case, the easiest approach is duck-typing.

```
if (myError && myError.stack && myError.message) {
  // it's an error, probably
}
```

However, duck-typing may produce false positives if you have non-error objects that contain `stack` and `message` properties.

Comment: @AurélienRibon It works just fine with a `ReferenceError` instance. You're checking the global `ReferenceError` object. Try this: `try { foo } catch (e) { console.log(e instanceof Error) }` It logs `true`. If you are trying to check the global `ReferenceError` object for some reason, you can use `Error.isPrototypeOf(ReferenceError)`

Comment: @AurélienRibon (Uh, also, yeah, wasn't sure if you were saying "This won't work with a ReferenceError" which is incorrect, or if you were just pointing out "This won't work with the global ReferenceError object" which is absolutely correct, although I'm having a hard time coming up with a situation where one would be checking that, but that may say more about my lack of imagination than the validity of the use case).

Comment: Haha, sorry about that guys, I was just locked into a strange error where all my `ReferenceError` instances were not instances of `Error`. This was due to a call to `vm.runInNewContext()` in node, where all standard prototypes are redefined. All my results were not instances of standard objects. I was looking in SO about this, and fell into this thread :)

Comment: You can try `const error = (err instanceof Error || err instanceof TypeError) ? err : new Error(err.message ? err.message : err);`

Comment: how do you check if its an `instanceof` a specific type of error tho?

Comment: @PrimitiveNom `myError instanceof SyntaxError` or `myError instanceof RangeError` and so on.

Answer (score 40):

I asked the original question -  @Trott's answer is surely the best.

However with JS being a dynamic language and with there being so many JS runtime environments, the `instanceof` operator can fail especially in front-end development when crossing boundaries such as iframes. See:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5886

*If you are ok with duck typing, this should be good:*

```
let isError = function(e){
   return e && e.stack && e.message;
};
```

I personally prefer statically typed languages, but if you are using a dynamic language, it's best to embrace a dynamic language for what it is, rather than force it to behave like a statically typed language.

if you wanted to get a little more precise, you could do this:

```
       let isError = (e) => {
         return e && 
                e.stack && 
                e.message && 
                typeof e.stack === 'string' && 
                typeof e.message === 'string';
        };
```

Comment: I prefer this version when writing a utility function or library. It doesn't constrain users to one particular global context and also properly handles deserialized errors from JSON.

Comment: thanks, yeah in many cases, if it looks like an error, we can treat like an error. in some cases duck typing is totally acceptable, in some cases it's not acceptable at all, in this case, perfectly fine.

Comment: I did some debugging using a debugger, and stack and message really do appear to be the only two non-native properties on Error instances.

Comment: @Trott you might be interested to know about the `instanceof` operator failing in some cases, see the linked article.

Comment: This is actually the simplest so it works with the different types of errors (i.e. `Error`, `ReferenceError`, ...). And in my environment, the `instanceof` fails miserably in many circumstances.

Comment: I personally would use `const` for isError. As it is probably not intended to change.

Comment: @AlexanderMills I see 'name' as another non-native property, at least in current Chrome, but it seems fragile and implementation-dependent to rely on that. Duck-typing it is, I'd say.

Comment: Note that this does not work for `new Error()`. Maybe just remove the check for `e.message` being truthy?

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) to easily check if an object is an [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), which will work for different frames as well.

```
function isError(obj){
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Error]";
}
```

```js
function isError(obj){
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Error]";
}
console.log("Error:", isError(new Error));
console.log("RangeError:", isError(new RangeError));
console.log("SyntaxError:", isError(new SyntaxError));
console.log("Object:", isError({}));
console.log("Array:", isError([]));
```

This behavior is guaranteed by the ECMAScript Language Specification.

[`Object.prototype.toString`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2):

> When the toString method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If the this value is undefined, return "[object Undefined]".
> 2. If the this value is null, return "[object Null]".
> 3. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.
> 4. Let class be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of O.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings "[object ", class, and "]".

[Properties of Error Instances](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.5):

> Error instances inherit properties from the Error prototype object and their `[[Class]]` internal property value is "Error". Error instances have no special properties.

Comment: I'm not sure I love this. I don't know if there is any standard that says that when stringified an error has to be exactly of this form. I would think it would depend on the implementation...

Comment: @Aaron That's not true. I have edited my answer with excerpts from the ECMAScript Language Specification.

Comment: This is the best solution with fewest (none?) downsides.

Answer (score 19):

## TypeScript solution

You can [define a user-defined type guard, simply need to define a function whose return type is a type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

You can check if a variable is error like this

```
const isError = (err: unknown): err is Error => err instanceof Error;
```

then inside try catch validate that like this

```
try {
  login(username, password);
} catch (err) {
  if (isError(err)) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

Comment: I believe this is a typescript solution.

Comment: Note: the [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469297/2788872) from the accepted answer apply the same.

Answer (score 11):

```
var myError = new Error('foo');
myError instanceof Error // true
var myString = "Whatever";
myString instanceof Error // false
```

Only problem with this is

```
myError instanceof Object // true
```

An alternative to this would be to use the constructor property.

```
myError.constructor === Object // false
myError.constructor === String // false
myError.constructor === Boolean // false
myError.constructor === Symbol // false
myError.constructor === Function // false
myError.constructor === Error // true
```

Although it should be noted that this match is very specific, for example:

```
myError.constructor === TypeError // false
```

Answer (score 5):

For those, who're looking for some 'official' way (like I did), this is [what MDN recommends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#conditional_catch-blocks):

```
try {
  myRoutine();
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof RangeError) {
    // statements to handle this very common expected error
  } else {
    throw e;  // re-throw the error unchanged
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use obj.constructor.name to check the "class" of an object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Function_names_in_classes

For Example

```
var error = new Error("ValidationError");
console.log(error.constructor.name);
```

The above line will log "Error" which is the class name of the object. This could be used with any classes in javascript, if the class is not using a property that goes by the name "name"

Comment: This is not reliable when minifying code and using error subclasses

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Trott for your code, I just used the same code and added with a real time working example for the benefit of others.

```html
<html>
<body >

<p>The **instanceof** operator returns true if the specified object is an instance of the specified object.</p>



<script>
 var myError = new Error("TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"); // error type when element is not defined
 myError instanceof Error // true
 
 
 
 
 function test(){
 
 var v1 = document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML ="zunu"; // to change with this
 
 try {
    var v1 = document.getElementById("myidd").innerHTML ="zunu"; // exception caught
    } 
    
 catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Error) {
   console.error(e.name + ': ' + e.message) // error will be displayed at browser console
    }
  }
  finally{
  var v1 = document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML ="Text Changed to Zunu"; // finally innerHTML changed to this.
 }
 
 }
 
</script>
<p id="myid">This text will change</p>
<input type="button" onclick="test();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, it's 2020 - please don't use var in SO posts

Comment: @refaelio hey it's 2022, we do our things respectfully, `var` is still correct in newest versions of JavaScript

Comment: Let's just be clear, respectful or not, nobody should ever be using 'var' anymore in modern javascript code.  There is no legitimate reason to use 'var' and putting it in stack overflow posts is a very effective way to propagate bad behavior.  If you don't believe me, just do a tiny bit of research and you'll see why.  There's a reason most linters have a 'no-var' rule.

Comment: Sorry if I was disrespectful. Please note that var is obsolete and should not be used. Use let or const. Keep in mind that answering in stackoverflow has implications on people that are trying to learn and answers like this hinder their progress and confuse them more than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `error.name`

```js
function _err(type = false) {
    if(type) {
        throw new TypeError('Oh crap!')
    }
    throw new Error('Oh crap!')
}

try {
    _err(true)
} catch (error) {
    console.log(typeof error.name, error.name, error.name === 'TypeError', error instanceof Error)
}

try {
    _err()
} catch (error) {
    console.log(typeof error.name, error.name, error.name === 'Error', error instanceof Error)
}
```

Comment: For RangeError, `e.name` gives "RangeError" and not "Error". I assume other errors types have different ".name"s. Not very useful.

Comment: But the base class is `Error`, so `new RangeError() instanceof Error`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the following condition:

```
if (e instanceof ErrorType) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use this for different types of errors

```
function isError(val) {
  return (!!val && typeof val === 'object')
    && ((Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Error]')
      || (typeof val.message === 'string' && typeof val.name === 'string'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the answer from @iota a bit further and check the test object's internal `[[Prototype]]` property via `getPrototypeOf()` or the deprecated `__proto__` property.

If the object is an error, it inherits from `Error.prototype`. So maybe something like this:

```
// the object you want to check 
const objectToCheck = new Error();

// current way
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(objectToCheck) === Error.prototype);  /* true*/

// deprecated way
console.log(objectToCheck.__proto__ === Error.prototype);  /* true */
```